# Passing Information Between Components based on a Input

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

How can I implement this in a way where everything the value on component 1 or 2 is changed, the value on the other component is updated, using a Service!. I know how to make this work using Output and Input, but using a service I'm stuck. I actually want to implement something more robust than the showed here, but first I need to understand the part of interaction of input. If that was a click, easy, whenever a click the button, send the information to the service, updates, and send to its subscriber. But with input, I can't find a way to make this work. Thanks for any help.
Also, if there is any advice as to understanding the logic behind the input element I would be very happy. Like, anything that I could read on that.

Component 1

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorServiceService } from '../service/behavior-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-childtwo',
  templateUrl: './childtwo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./childtwo.component.css']
})
export class ChildtwoComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor(private behaviorService: BehaviorServiceService) { }
  data;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.behaviorService.currentMessage
      .subscribe((message)=>{
        this.data = message
      })
  }
}
```

Component 2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorServiceService } from '../service/behavior-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-childone',
  templateUrl: './childone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./childone.component.css']
})
export class ChildoneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private behaviorService: BehaviorServiceService) { }
  data;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.behaviorService.currentMessage
      .subscribe((message)=>{
        this.data = message
      })
  }

}
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BehaviorServiceService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('string')
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable()

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){

  }

  changeMessage(message){
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to implement lifecycle hook ngOnChanges().

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges